# tasks package: items are in two line with 4 columns and 4 items

Tags: tasks

I write some choice questions into `beamer` frame, after some research, here is my code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{tasks,CJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{utf8}{bsmi}
\begin{frame}
\transwipe
1.Which one you want to choose?
\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[A].,debug=true](4)
\task A
\task B
\task C
\task D
\end{tasks}
\end{frame}
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

output with pdflatex:
[image]
But I don't want the `D` choice goto the second line, I want them stay in one line, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in your question, not just a code fragment. Adding your fragment to an [MWE of my choise](https://justpaste.it/zhpb) leads to a [4 column output](http://i.imgur.com/9rc3lHG.png).

Comment: @alwaysask Thanks for your advice. I still got two line with your code, what additional information should I attach?

Comment: Now your MWE needs an `\end{document}` at the end. Most likely your TeX installation needs an update. You can compile your code using [online compilers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online) to test the result against your installation -- for example on [papeeria.com](http://i.imgur.com/1fVNIe9.png).

Comment: @alwaysask but I installed it with the latest ISO file yesterday...

Comment: Generally, ISO's don't get updated. Please point me to the link you downloaded the ISO and/or give details of your system (OS, TeX installation etc).

Comment: @alwaysask I added full import of packages in the question hope it helps.

Comment: @alwaysask the ctan mirror I download the ISO: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CTAN/ os:ubuntu gnome 16.04 installed without most of language packages. Install position etc..was default value. Tlmgr was updated after install.

Comment: Well, the `aspectratio`setting is what leads to two lines, you can remove the `CJK` related code. Any aspect ratio different from 43 (4:3 -- I think it's the default) breaks the `tasks` line in two. Now you can see the importance of posting a full MWE rather than just code fragments. (your TeX installation is fine).

Comment: @alwaysask oh yeah, but I need use Chinese language in tasks, without cjk I cannot deal with that, is there any better solution for UTF8 support?

Comment: Keep `CJK` in your document. It's just that to demonstrate the issue you have in this question, `CJK` has no [bad] influence. The issue (tasks breaks in two lines) is present without CJK as well. So, according to the MWE guiding rules in the link I gave you, it can be removed.

Comment: It seems that `tasks` cannot compute the right width for the tasks with beamer when `aspectratio=169` is in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the newest version of `tasks`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{tasks}[2019-10-04]% version 1.0 or newer

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \transwipe
  1. Which one you want to choose?
  \begin{tasks}[label=\Alph*.,debug=true](4)
    \task A
    \task B
    \task C
    \task D
  \end{tasks}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

PS: Please note that the option `counter-format` has been dropped in version 1.0. The functionality is included in `label` which is now set the same way as in `enumitem`.