# Are there any online LaTeX editors that provide the latest packages?

Tags: online

I need to use a feature that was recently introduced in the [`pgfgantt`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt?lang=en) package. Currently [Overleaf uses TeX Live 2016](https://www.overleaf.com/help/30-what-packages-do-you-support).

Since opening an account on [each of the existing online services](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1654/98306) is impractical for an individual, I launch this question to the broad TEX.SE community.

Does anybody know of any online LaTeX editors that *specifically* provide the latest packages?

Comment: If you need something from an "easy-to-install" package, you could simply download the latest version from ctan and upload it to your project on overleaf.

Comment: @HenriMenke I disagree. My question is not a duplicate because I am specifically asking for online tools that provide the latest packages. The question that you are pointing to does not provide that information and I already linked that source in the body of my question.

Comment: So basically you are now asking the community to do the tedious work for you and extract the version information from all the online editors?  Downvoted for no effort.

Comment: A reasonable question. @samcarter seems to have the response. Understand that there is a difference between the "latest texlive" (which involves executable binaries) and the "latest packages" (which might not rely on the latest binaries).

Comment: @HenriMenke Please don't make such accusation. I always ask when I need help. I learn a lot from this community and I respect it, just like I respect your criticism.

Comment: The package you want to use (pgfgantt) just needs one .sty file. Just upload this file with your project and you should be all set.

Answer (score 10):

The following test document reports version information about pdfTeX and TeX live.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pdftexbanner
\end{document}
```

As of March 15, 2018:

#### Overleaf

[image]

#### Sharelatex

[image]

#### verbosus

[image]

#### Papeeria

[image]