# What pdflatex version and what arguments does overleaf use?

Tags: overleaf, versions

I have a code which works fine in `overleaf` but not on my local computer. Regardless of what is wrong with my code, What `pdflatex` version and what arguments does `overleaf` use?

I followed the log that `overleaf` gives me.

I read the `log` and three questions remain for me.

1- How come my fresh installed pdflatex is version of while theirs is 2017? Do they use development version instead of the stable one? (BTW, my ubuntu is 16.04 not 18.10).

2- What arguments do they use?

3- Do they follow `pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex` pattern?

**PS**. The linked question is not related to my question at all. I do not need any latest support. Please read the question again.

**PS**. Dear SE users. I don't care about my code problem. I only look for the answer to those three questions.

Overleaf logs:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.7.12)  12 JAN 2019 02:14
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(/compile/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip43
\bibsep=\skip44
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count87
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/bibentry.sty
Package: bibentry 2007/10/30 1.5 (PWD)
) (/compile/output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
(/compile/output.bbl)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 13.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
File: omscmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 13.

Overfull \hbox (19.59796pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--14
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Geert Lit-jens, Thijs Kooi, Babak Eht-e-shami Be-jnordi, Ar-n
aud Arindra Adiyoso
 []


Overfull \hbox (12.67789pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--15
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Matthew Collins, Ben BB Booth, Glen R Har-ris, James M Mur-ph
y, David MH
 []

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/compi
le/output.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 596 strings out of 492990
 7131 string characters out of 6132621
 60213 words of memory out of 5000000
 4223 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3986 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,19p,137b,145s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmsy10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on /compile/output.pdf (1 page, 41124 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 20 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 13 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Local computer:

```
pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
```

Comment: @Dozam: The reason for Overleaf using an older version is because they have a large network of users and updating it could cause problems. Sure, it may work without problem if they update it, but until they've done sufficient testing to confirm this, they'd rather let sleeping dogs lie, I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any online LaTeX editors that provide the latest packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420236/are-there-any-online-latex-editors-that-provide-the-latest-packages)

Comment: This website is not the [Overleaf support](https://www.overleaf.com/contact).

Comment: Install TeX Live directly from tug.org and don't use the linux depositories.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I do not understand why you concluded my question is linked to such a question.

Comment: @Dozam you have edited the question to make it clearer now, and Carlatex had answered it but in your original question you only showed one version (LaTeX2e 2017-04-05) without saying whether that was the local or overleaf version, so Henri's comment (and mine above) was assuming that the overleaf one was older, however it is your local copy that is older.  (no need to respond to this, I'm just explaining why the earlier comments do not fit, I will delete my earlier ones)

Comment: To make my earlier comment more clear: ubuntu 16.04 comes with an old version of tex live. Overleaf has a newer version of tex live. Both are outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `\listfiles` at the very beginning of your document.

Click on the icon "Logs and output files" and then on "View Row Logs".

You'll find

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.1.12)  12 JAN 2019 07:48
entering extended mode
```

and if you search for `*File List*` you'll find the list of the used package versions, below an example.

As moewe pointed out, [Overleaf uses the `latexmk` build tool to automatically build your project](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F) and, as for the command line options to the LaTeX call, they must be using something like `-interaction=nonstopmode`, but the log snippet in the OP suggests `shell escape`/`write18` is enabled.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 tikz-cd.sty    2014/10/30 v0.9e Commutative diagrams with tikz
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: Interestingly your `.log` shows TeX live 2015 and that in the OP TeX live 2017. I believe that new v2 projects run on 2017.

Comment: @moewe For the example, I run on v2 a project migrated from v1, maybe they keep the old version for old projects?

Comment: I think they do, but I'm not sure. I think I read a blogpost about this a while ago.

Comment: As for the command line options to the LaTeX call, they are probably largely irrelevant, but they must be using something like `-interaction=nonstopmode`. But the log snippet in the OP suggests shell escape/`write18` is enabled.

Comment: @moewe According to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464716/problem-with-the-glossarybib2gls-on-overleaf#comment1169485_464716) older projects on Overleaf may be set to use an old TeX Live image. (No idea if it's possible to make the project use a newer version.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I tried any button, but I didn't find how to change it.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I couldn't find anything either. Perhaps it's not possible, but it would be useful if it could be done.