# Error: Undefined control sequence using \cite, \textcite, \parencite

Tags: biblatex, citing

I tried the answer in [How to cite a page number in-text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509637/how-to-cite-a-page-number-in-text/509655?noredirect=1#comment1289965_509655) in my work, but there is an error:

```
Undefined control sequence
```

The details:

```
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
```

[image]

My MWE:

02background.tex file:

```
this is cite \cite[150]{gaver1986auditory}\\
This book is done by \textcite[150]{gaver1986auditory}\\
ABC book is done \parencite[150]{gaver1986auditory}\\
```

main.tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}  % Remove draft option to show figures (for final draft), otherwise keep for faster production

\usepackage{uorthesis}  % Loads the LaTeX style package

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
% style=authoryear, 
 style=authoryear-comp,
% citestyle=authoryear, 
dashed=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
giveninits,
uniquename=init]{biblatex}

% for the purpose to change "paper title" to 'paper title' in reference
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
% \usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
% for the purpose to change "paper title" to 'paper title' in reference

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}
  {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
% for Quoting AuthorA (1999: 22), Part 2



% for Quoting AuthorA (1999: 22), Part 1
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{postnotedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
% for Quoting AuthorA (1999: 22), Part 1

\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}



\begin{document}

\include{chapters/02-background}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Bibliography}}{}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

uorthesis.sty file:

```
% This defines everything necessary for a thesis
% Master's/PhD at UoR (or anywhere else).
%
% Do what you will with this package
% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{uorthesis}
  [2018/01/18 v0.01 LaTeX package for UOR thesis]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep} % Removes too much vertical spacing in lists
\usepackage{booktabs}           % makes tables look good
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % For page number in the upper right (required) and other running headers(optional)
\usepackage{setspace}           % For double-spacing (required)
\usepackage{titlesec}           % For keeping chapter/chapter titles single-spaced
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % For the flag determining if front matter goes into the TOC
\usepackage{float}              % Helps float images to the top
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
% Define custom colors
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=darkblue]{hyperref}           % Adds hyperlinks in the pdf
% \usepackage{csquotes}           % Makes quotes look good %cancel off for the single quote in referencing the journal title
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, justification=centering]{caption}

% Header formatting for regular pages
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\it\small\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\small\thepage}

% Header formatting for chapter title pages
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[R]{\small\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

% Formatting of chapter and chapter titles: keep them single-spaced in the midst of double-spaced text



\endinput
%%
%% End of file `uorthesis.sty'.
```

reference.bib file:

```
@article{gaver1986auditory,
  title={Auditory icons: Using sound in computer interfaces},
  author={Gaver, William W},
  journal={Human-computer interaction},
  volume={2},
  number={2},
  pages={167--177},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

Comment: Completely off-topic, but if the `W` in `author={Gaver, William W},` is supposed to be an initial and not the full name, you should write `author={Gaver, William W.},` instead.

Comment: @moewe, thanks. you are brillant!. I actually get the `Bibtex` from `google scholar`. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Auditory+icons%3A+Using+sound+in+computer+interfaces&btnG=#d=gs_cit&u=%2Fscholar%3Fq%3Dinfo%3AkWY7ofSbRkoJ%3Ascholar.google.com%2F%26output%3Dcite%26scirp%3D0%26hl%3Den and https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.bib?q=info:kWY7ofSbRkoJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=CgVSZ3NQEP3npXhl0as:AAGBfm0AAAAAXZBgyatZEdbgfwacEst7ZkQy0lJhb22h&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAXZBgyZXRj6GMH8nHYlw_bLATWAyJ_PW9&scisf=4&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en

Comment: I suggest to *always* double check the information you get from Google Scholar or any other source. I usually write my `.bib` entry by hand and don't use Google Scholar, so I can't say anything about the quality of the data provided there, but there is an extensive list of common problems of software-generated `.bib` files at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the error message carefully you can see that the exact command LaTeX complains about is `\mknormrange`. (Usually the offending command is the last in the first line of the error message.)

This means you are using an older version of `biblatex` that doesn't support that command. Replace

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
```

with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
```

---

Note that [Overleaf have just updated their systems to TeX live 2018](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-upgrade-september-2019), where `\mknormrange` is supported. So if you start a new project now or clone your project into a new one, the code with `\mknormrange` should work without error.

Comment: thanks. it works. Between, how to check `\mknormrange` version?

Comment: You can have a look at the `.log` files (press on the the "Logs and output files" button next to the "Recompile" button and click on "View raw logs"). They will report the version of all packages that you use. The current `biblatex` version is v3.13, the newest Overleaf can offer you is v3.12. But depending on when you started writing your project, you may get a much older version. `\mknormrange` was introduced in `biblatex` v3.11.

Comment: if in my `overleaf` main page, I copy my previous project (created in year 2018). Will it be get the newest version?

Comment: @aan I don't know, the blog post I linked (https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-upgrade-september-2019) has a section called *How can I switch to TeX Live 2018 for existing projects?* and mentions *cloning* projects to get TeX live 2018, but I'm not sure how exactly that works. If you can't get things to work, you can contact Overleaf's support, from what I've read they are very eager to help (not sure how quickly the respond on a Sunday) and can usually resolve issues like this quickly.

Comment: @aan See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469777/35864 for more instructions on finding out your package versions.

Comment: thanks. Brillant!