# Latex editor/compiler for Windows and Powerpoint

Tags: windows, powerpoint

I am using Windows in my daily work. Would you like to recommend on Latex editor/compiler for Windows. Sometimes, I need to add a lot of math formula for the PPT files, what are the best way to use Latex along with Powerpoint? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you need a lot of math formula, use beamer and any TeX editor you like instead of Powerpoint and you will be much happier ;)

Comment: MS Office's native equation editor has improved over the years. So using that for math formulas in your PPT would suffice most of the time. It would also give you better alignment than pasting pictures of TeX generated formulas.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SX! As @TeXnician suggested, you can use [beamer](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) to create presentations. If you prefer to use Microsoft Powerpoint (or something similar) as you main environment, then I highly suggest [codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). It allows you to insert LaTeX formulas and export them as PDF, GIF, PNG, and even SVG format. SVG is the best that suits you in my opinion because you can scale the image in Powerpoint and it won't get pixelated. Another perk is that allows you to insert symbols with a click of a mouse :). You don't memorize the commands/symbol names, one click and it is there for you.

Comment: I would highly recommend the insert SVG format and here is a Microsoft link for 365 https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-svg-images-in-microsoft-office-365-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c alternatives to codecogs are here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488049/alternatives-to-overleaf-i-e-instant-tex-compiling-without-sign-in

Answer (score 3):

Personally I can recommend this type of program that is very useful and that I often use in my Power Point slides. It's called **KLatexFormula** and you can find a the link https://klatexformula.sourceforge.io/.

It is free and it is very easy to use and to generate images with LaTeX code (from the classic PNG to SVG). Here into this page you can see the screenshots: https://klatexformula.sourceforge.io/screenshots.

The program is very convenient mainly for two reasons: the first is the symbol panel because you may not remember how to write the code of a certain symbol (a Greek letter, a mathematical operator, etc. ...) in the language of LaTeX. The second is the library of formulas, where there are already examples of formulas and diagrams, and where you can integrate your formulas so that you can easily copy them in the future.

Another of the advantages of KLaTeXFormula is the very simple and intuitive interface that provides a help system that explains the various functions for less practical users of the LaTeX world. The program requires a LaTeX distribution to be installed and possibly Inkscape if you want to export your formula as a SVG image.

Answer (score 2):

You need a TeX-distribution:

- [TeX Live](https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html)

or

- [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org)

And for PowerPoint integration:

- [IguanaTex](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/)