# Alternative to Overleaf (realtime LaTeX collaboration) With the Ability to have Multiple Collaborators but with no Charge

Tags: editors, overleaf, online, collaboration

I teach a class in which students write several lab reports in LaTeX, and up until very recently I required students to use Overleaf. This allowed groups of 3-4 to write lab reports in LaTeX with real-time collaboration. It was pretty awesome!

All of a sudden today, people in my class started noticing that the ability to collaborate on a given document with more than 1 other person was now behind a paywall. Since the minimum group size in my class is 3, Overleaf is no longer nearly as useful to us. (While it is possible that my institution will one day provide a site license, that would take ~a year, and I'm ideally looking for solutions that I can implement this week!)

**Are there any free alternative online LaTeX editors that allow real-time collaboration, but do not charge for the ability to have multiple collaborators?**

(By the way, I am aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488049/alternatives-to-overleaf-i-e-instant-tex-compiling-without-sign-in), but the question and its answers focus on editors that do not require a sign-in, and not on the ability to collaborate. Requiring a sign-in is not the issue for me.)

Comment: Those lab reports absolutely need to be done with LaTex?

Comment: Is it a physics class or a LaTeX class? Anyway, install it on one machine, and let the students do their job.

Comment: Both -- students need to be able to work on the assignments on their own time, in collaboration with each other. I'm looking for a better solution than emailing files back and forth/dropbox/etc, and more user-friendly than the GitHub implementation.

Comment: _[BIG CAVEAT AND DISCLAIMER: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ Might the link-sharing feature be useful here? This allows users on the Free plan to work with more collaborators, using a shareable read-and-edit link. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Sharing_a_project

Comment: +1, I would add "with the ability to have multiple collaborators but with no charge" to the title of your question.

Comment: @LianTzeLim Wow -- I feel dumb for not figuring that out myself. Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. If you would like to get credit for the answer I will happily accept it. Otherwise I'll answer the question myself later.

Comment: Not at all, go ahead! :D For completeness' sake might I suggest to include the link https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Sharing_a_project to your answer, to cover different ways of sharing a project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With many thanks to @LianTzeLim, the solution to my problem is so simple that it is actually contained within Overleaf itself!

Adding collaborators may be behind a paywall, but "link sharing" is still a free service. To collaborate in real-time on your LaTeX document via link sharing, you can do the following:

1. Have one group member create a project in Overleaf as you normally
   would.
2. Click the "Share" Button in the top, right-hand corner of the
   screen.
3. Press the "Turn On Link Sharing" link in the box that
   appears.
4. Copy the link beneath the box titled "Anyone with this link
   can edit this project," and share the link with the other members of
   your group (e.g. via email)
5. Anyone with that link should be able to edit the LaTeX document, and you should be able to all edit it in real-time!

At present I have not heard any complaints from my students. I will update this if that changes.

source: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Sharing_a_project

Comment: Nope @Daniel -- Currently using link sharing in the class I'm teaching, and all 4 group-members are collaborating just fine!

Comment: Oops, you're correct. Sharing via link and sharing with collaborators are different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use papeeria. Its collaborative, free and reliable.
https://www.papeeria.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/231060)

Answer (score -1):

You may also consider [HandWiki encyclopedia](https://handwiki.org/) for collaborative editing. It is totally free. Note that you will use the Wiki syntax, and later can convert it to LaTeX. Handwiki is particularly friendly to LaTeX since it allows to import BibTeX files, and your math equations will use the same LaTeX syntax