# How I can give the privilege of using LaTeX in my website?

Tags: pdftex

I want to build a researcher blog website, where multiple researcher can work on one journal like google docs. For research paper, all of us choose latex. So I have to put a latex compiler in the website. Can anyone give basic idea how to do it?

Comment: If you only want compilers and build everything else manually, have a look at the Island of TeX's docker images. But currently, your aim is unclear to me.

Comment: Could using mathJax be an option, if it is just for LaTeX like syntax for some simple enough equations?

Comment: what researchers need. just like overleaf.

Comment: @dip the maths rendering capabilities of mathJax, as seen on several stack exchange sites, probably meets most of the needs for writing most vanilla documents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way is probably to install the open source [Overleaf](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf) (formerly ShareLaTeX) on your server. **Just be sure you read up on how to run a LaTeX compiler securely, because you don't want your server to be hacked.** Probably you will have to put LaTeX into some sort of sandbox container.

You can also look at the question [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online) and see if any of the linked projects suit your needs.

Or you could embed a project on on an existing online editor website (like [overleaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com/)) in an `<iframe>`. But then everyone needs an account there.

Comment: Overleaf and ShareLaTeX merged together. Overleaf existed together with ShareLaTeX before.

Comment: thanks. gonna try

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes I know. What I meant is that in the past, you could only use ShareLaTeX on your own server, because Overleaf was closed source as far as I know. And Overleaf is using the editor component from ShareLaTeX now, and renamed it to Overleaf. That's why I wrote "formerly ShareLaTeX".